Why do dogs bark during fajr?
Why do dogs bark especially during the fajr adhan ? I know dogs bark during adhan and know the reason also they see sth that don'tsee. But I mostly hear them barking only during the fajr adhan very loudly. Is their any specific reason behind fajr adhan?

Perhaps by crying loudly dogs express sadness that why many humans are not going for fajar salah after hearing Azan.
